# How to change Java advanced setting by VBscript or batch?

Tags: java, batch-file, vbscript

To be more specific, how can I change the "Check for certificate revocation using" setting to "Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP)" by VBscript or batch?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these properties are stored in `%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\deployment.properties`

to disable `CRLs` you need to add `deployment.security.validation.crl=false` . So here's the solution

```
@echo deployment.security.validation.crl=false>>"%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\deployment.properties"
```

to restore these settings you need to delete this line.And probably you'll need admin permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! But on my computer the properties file located at %userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties